# Create custom input box with autofill

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new in html and css. I am creating my first design using html,css and bootsrap. I have problem while creating custom input box with autofill options.
[image]

Here is the fiddle which i am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Home</title>

    </head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up">
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-search">
        <div class="custom-container">
            <div class="center-div">

                <div class="banner-form">
                    <form class="">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="US">
                            </div>
                            <button class="relative br-right pv2" data-test="search-button" aria-label="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="banner-img">
                        <img src="images/banner-home.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>           
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d8bg05o6/7/

Please help

Comment: Which problem do you have?

Comment: I have problem create like these textbox

Comment: Already created the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d8bg05o6/7/

Comment: do you want to make same design as image in HTML ?